# Неправильный реферер при переходе, урл со специфическим поддоменом (только в хроме)

Tags: url, маршрутизация

В интернет магазине есть регионы с уникальными поддоменами. При переходах со страницы на страницу в поддоменном регионе реферер всегда хранит значение протокол+поддомен+домен, то есть откидывает путь к ресурсу и параметры.

Например, переходим со страницы карточки товара (`https://spb.magazin.ru/tovar/kosilka/huter/huter_motokultivator_gmc-6.5/`) на страницу авторизации (`https://www.magazin.ru/login/`), то в реферер запишется только `https://spb.magazin.ru/`.

Если мы находимся не в поддоменном регионе, то реферер будет корректным `https://www.magazin.ru/tovar/kosilka/huter/huter_motokultivator_gmc-6.5/`

Не важно, в каком регионе воспроизводить этот кейс, он работает для любого специфического поддомена.
Подскажите, по каким причинам реферер может формироваться неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит для защиты от отслеживания, это новый всемирный тренд. Ради него даже идею CDN для скриптов "сломали", что тут какой-то реферер…

Заголовок Referer в протоколе HTTP никогда не являлся обязательным, так что самое время перестать использовать его, пока совсем не отменили. К примеру, если вам нужно вернуться со страницы входа на предыдущую - ссылку на эту самую предыдущую полагается передавать параметром в URL. Как-то так: `https://www.magazin.ru/login/?returnSite=spb&returnPath=tovar/kosilka/huter/huter_motokultivator_gmc-6.5/`.

Comment: Спасибо, очень содержательно! Не знала об этом.
Реферер мне нужен для редиректа. Пока искала решение, вспомнила о такой приятной штуке, как `history.back()`